# Staging of the Installation in Maintenance mode

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I'm using Installshield 2018 and ive encountered strange behavior in Suite project. 
The suite has two primary packages and several secondary, the sources of the packages are set to be downloaded from the source media (meaning they are next to the setup.exe).

When i want to add some of the secondary packages in the maintenance mode and click on one of the pages on button where browse a file function is, which sets the path to the file to PROPERTYXY. The packages dont stage. It ends up with the error dialog saying that the package is not available and wants me to browse the .exe file that i want to install.. When i click the change button, the starting directory is the one, i browsed for the file browse. If i copy the source files (the packages) into folder where the browsed file is, it works again.

And if i dont click the button to browse for a file, everything works perfectly again.

Am i missing something? or is it some error in installshield?